# castellated holes size and spacing

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

I'm about to create surface mountable module with at least 65 castellated mounting holes but I am wondering about few things:

- Is there a minimum size for a castellated hole?
- Is there a minimum spacing between two castellated holes?
- Is it possible to make a PCB with castellated holes on all sides?

Is anyone familiar with this type of PCB?

Comment: These are all questions you should ask your board house.